# How to disable logging in neo4j-ogm

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I understand that the question can sound a little funny, but how do I disable logging in neo4j-ogm? I have added an logback.xml file to my conf directory which is in my classpath. The logback.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>    
    <!--
      ~ Set the required log level for the OGM components here.
      ~ To just see Cypher statements set the level to "info"
      ~ For finer-grained diagnostics, set the level to "debug".
    -->
    <logger name="org.neo4j.ogm" level="OFF" />

    <root level="off">
                <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

which is taken from [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/) . The loglevel=off is taken from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm)

I want to deploy my program for production and I need logs from console. But with neo4j logging the logfile increases 1GB per day with the following type logs:

```
14:20:13.281 [Thread-14] DEBUG o.n.o.d.http.request.HttpRequest - Response is OK
14:20:13.289 [Thread-14] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - looking for concrete class to resolve label: Leaf
14:20:13.289 [Thread-14] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - concrete class found: com.mycompany.Leaf. comparing with what's already been found previously...
14:20:13.289 [Thread-14] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - Page resolving class:  com.mycompany.Leaf
14:20:13.290 [Thread-14] DEBUG org.neo4j.ogm.MetaData - looking for concrete class to resolve label: Root
etc...
```

Details:

The program is a jsvc daemon which logs console to log/log.txt.

neo4j-version: 2.0.0 - M01

java -version : oracle java 7

Comment: Did you solve this problem because it bugs me too!

Comment: Nope. I  ended up writing my own small implementation(which does only what I want).

Answer (score 3):

The question was raised years ago, but for all using Stack Overflow as knowledge database, I want to record an additional solution for current environments. Most of the Neo4j log entries concern query statements and the already mentioned "unwind" messages. So, you are using a Spring Boot environment (2.0.3.RELEASE) in conjunction with the spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j artifact? Just add the following line to your `/src/main/resources/application.properties` file to disable the messages:

### Using the Bold driver

```
logging.level.org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest = WARN
```

### Using the embedded driver

```
logging.level.org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest = WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help your case but I had exploding "UNWIND" logs issue and found this hacky way to fix it. It just disables an internal logger I found in the source code. You could do something similar if your found the logger class in source code:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

Comment: or
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest").setLevel(Level.WARNING);

Answer (score 0):

After hours working on it, I finally find the problem!
I was using the wrong dependencies of "slf4j".

**Wrong dependency:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Correct dependency:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

And I just use the file "log4j2.xml" to make the correct level of logs.
I hope this can help anyone!